# push notification works only send from ios to android not from ios to ios / android to ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send push notification from iOS to android works fine. But not from iOS to iOS / android to iOS. I am using parse.com. Pushes sent status shows 0 when i sent from iOS to iOS. didReceiveRemoteNotification is not getting called.

```
// Register for Push Notitications
CGFloat systemVersion  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if(systemVersion > 8.0)
{
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // Register for push notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your push certificate because your are not getting notification on IOS. It means, either issue in certificate or code on server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "if(systemVersion > 8.0)" should be "if(systemVersion >= 8.0)". Anyway, here you have my code that uses respondsToSelector.

```
// Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
UIApplication* application=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

} else {
    // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```